# How can I find out the Objective-C generics type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, generics

Xcode 7 contains an Objective-C variant, where you can define a type-hint for (homogenous) `NSArray` return values and properties, defined such as `NSArray<UIImage*>`.

I'd like to use this feature to rewrite my JSON-deserializer class (which needs such kind of type hints – previously I have solved this by adding a `-(Class)jsonHintForKey:(NSString*)key` to my classes that have homogenous arrays as properties.)

Do you know whether (and if so, how) I can use the Objective-C runtime to get the class of this new type hint at runtime?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The lightweight generics introduced in Xcode 7 are just compile time hints to help the compiler raise warnings, but at run time you get the same old behavior with your variable being just `NSArray`s of `id`s.

Source: [WWDC '15 "Swift and Objective-C Interoperability" session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=401)

See [the transcript of the talk](https://github.com/ASCIIwwdc/wwdc-session-transcripts/blob/master/2015/401.vtt#L2403):

> So the entire lightweight generics feature is based on a [type erasure model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Which means that the compiler has all of this rich static type information but it erases that information when generating code.

Comment: Good job on that source :)

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to do that.

Generics were introduced in objective-c to improve the bridge between swift and objective-c. The advantage it gives to objective-c is only **useful at compile time**, and I that information is lost at runtime.

Comment: Note that generics are not ported when `objective-c` classes are imported into `swift`, so I don't think bridging is the reason they were added to `objective-c`.