# Get array type in runtime objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Is there any ways in objective-c to find type of property which is declareted in next way:

`@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray<CustomClass *> *array;`

I can get type of this property as NSArray, but are any ways to get CustomClass type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to receive information about generics declaration in runtime. Objective-C generics is a recent addition to language. They are used for compile-time checks only, so no any additional runtime information created. Note, that generic declaration doesn't strictly prevent storing objects of other class in array - compiler warning may be suppressed, although it's a bad practice.

But, there is still a possibility to determine classes of objects, stored in array. For example, you can use code like `[array valueForKey:@"class"]` to receive array of classes, corresponding to each element.

Answer (score 1):

Type hints in lightweight generics are mainly used by compilers to raise warnings and it will not be available during runtime.

This SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866197/how-can-i-find-out-the-objective-c-generics-type) provides additional information and references to Apple docs/ videos. For convenience, I'm adding some information here.

> So the entire lightweight generics feature is based on a type erasure model. Which means that the compiler has all of this rich static type information but it erases that information when generating code.